# CosmosDb Graph: move node (and its edges) to different partition?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I'm using a partitioned CosmosDB graph collection. 
Is there a simple way to "move" a node (and its outbound links) from one partition to another? Can this be done atomically?

I tried this: (the partition key is '/tenantId')

```
//create the node
g.addV('testme').property('id','id123').property('tenantId','mytenant1')

//...create more nodes and edges...


//change node's partition key
g.V('id123').has('tenantId','mytenant1').property('tenantId','mytenant2')
// ^^^ fails:
// GraphRuntimeException ExceptionMessage :  
//   Gremlin Query Execution Error: 
//      Update Vertex Properties: The partition property cannot be updated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error explains, the partition key value cannot be updated. It's immutable.

However, if you delete the document and add it with an updated partition key value then that will work. Keep in mind that whatever you code in order to do that should have some rollback logic in it in case the new insertion fails.